# Does C++ require a destructor call for each placement new?

Tags: c++

I understand that placement new calls are usually matched with explicit calls to the destructor.  My question is: if I have no need for a destructor (no code to put there, and no member variables that have destructors) can I safely skip the explicit destructor call?

Here is my use case: I want to write C++ bindings for a C API.  In the C API many objects are accessible only by pointer.  Instead of creating a wrapper object that contains a single pointer (which is wasteful and semantically confusing).  I want
 to use placement new to construct an object at the address of the C object.  The C++ object will do nothing in its constructor or destructor, and its methods will do nothing but delegate to the C methods.  The C++ object will contain no virtual methods.

I have two parts to this question.

1. Is there any reason why this idea will not work in practice on any production compiler?
2. Does this technically violate the C++ language spec?

Comment: You mean actually calling the destructor yourself in code? You should (almost) NEVER do that.

Comment: Placement new is one of those rare times when you are supposed to.

Comment: @Josh: I don't think I understand the problem. Why not have the C object as the only data member of your C++ object? Then in your member functions, pass a pointer to that member into the C API function that you're delegating to.

Comment: @Josh: oh, do you mean that the C API returns a newly-allocated struct, and you want to "replace" it by calling placement new for your C++ object on the same memory? If so, then I'd make your object a pointer wrapper. It's *not* wasteful, because your objects replace the pointers that users would have held to the allocated objects anyway. And it shouldn't be confusing as long as you get your API right - either ban copying, or make clear that copies of a "handle" naturally refer to the same object, just like copies of pointers.

Comment: @Steve: to me it's semantically confusing to have an object which is logically a pointer but looks like a value.  In particular, it makes it much less obvious what will happen if you copy or assign it.  Also, having method calls like my_foo.Bar() instead of my_foo->Bar() seems wrong.

Comment: If you're sure of the memory layout of the object, then why not simply casting the pointer ?

Comment: @Steve: yes, that's correct.  Sorry, I think I misunderstood you previous question in my last comment.

Comment: @6502: that's an interesting (and much simpler) option!  Though that one seems more likely to violate a strict reading of the C++ spec.

Comment: @Josh: or, you could use a `shared_ptr` (or rather, a wrapper for one) as the "handle", with a custom deleter if necessary to clean up correctly as per the C API. This is logically a pointer and behaves like a value, but has the benefit of familiarity. It is "wasteful", though, in the sense that you pay for those shared ownership semantics, but no more so than all the other uses of `shared_ptr` in the world...

Comment: Quick question: you're not expecting the contents of the original object to be preserved in any way by the use of placement new, are you?

Comment: At the moment I'm favoring a simple reinterpret_cast to the C++ type.

Comment: @Charles: I was expecting that, was that not a safe assumption?

Comment: @John Haberman: Absolutely not. Placement new will destroy your old object.

Comment: @Charles:  Perhaps it might be better to say "placement new will obliterate your old object."  When you say "destroy" it seems to imply that it will call the destructor of the original object, which it won't do.

Comment: @James McNellis: Good point, although I can't edit it now. Then again, obliterate has the connotation of very violent and final eraditcation. It might not obliterate it in the sense that the memory and old byte values _might_ not be overwritten. It will cause your old object to be in a state of not existing any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you have a C object in memory and you want to initialize a C++ object with the same layout "over the top" of the existing object.

```
CppObject* cppobject = new (cobject) CppObject;
```

While there is no problem with not calling a destructor for the old object - whether this causes resource leaks or other issues is entirely down to the type of the old object and is a user code issue, not a language conformance issue - the fact that you reuse the memory for a new object means that the old object is no longer accessible.

Although the placement form of `operator new` must just return the address that it was given, there is nothing to stop the new expression itself wiping the memory for the new object before any constructor (if any) is called. Members of the new object that are not initialized according to C++ language rules have unspecified contents which definitely does not mean the same as having the contents of any old object that once lived in the memory being reused.

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: The standard stops placement new from wiping the memory before the ctor: "Intentionally performs no other action." [§18.4.1.3p3, C++03]  Unless I'm misunderstanding that.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: No that's the requirement for the placement form of `::operator new` and can be verified with an explicit call to `::operator new`. A new expression intializes a new object; there's nothing to stop the compiler to insert magic after the call to the appropriate `operator new` and before the object is initialized to reset the memory or, when parts of the object are left "uninitialized", filling these parts with junk values.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that if your class is POD (which it is, if it's true that it does nothing in the con/destructor, has no virtual member functions, and has no non-static data members with any of those things), then you don't need to call a constructor *or* a destructor, its lifetime is just the lifetime of the underlying memory. You can use it the same way that a struct is used in C, and you can call its member functions regardless of whether it has been constructed.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't really matter if the object is POD or not. Any object's lifetime will end when its storage is reused. Whether not calling a destructor will cause resource leaks or other bad things to happen is entirely a user code issue.

Comment: @Charles: I guess so, I was trying to point out that in addition to what the questioner wants, if his class is POD he doesn't need the placement new either.

Comment: Unless he wants to use a non-default constructor to initialize the object, which is often handy.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of placement new is to allow you to create object pools or align multiple objects together in contiguous memory space as with std::vector.

If the objects are C-structs then you do not need placement new to do this, you can simply use the C method of allocating the memory based on sizeof(struct Foo) where Foo is the struct name, and if you allocate multiple objects you may need to multiple the size up to a boundary for alignment.

However there is no need to placement-new the objects there, you can simply memcpy them in.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, yes you still need to call the destructor because other stuff has to happen.

Is there any reason why this idea will not work in practice on any production compiler?

You had damn well be sure your C++ object fits within the size of the C object.

Does this technically violate the C++ language spec?

No, but not everything that is to spec will work like you want.

Comment: Why is the destructor call needed?

Comment: @Charles: Even if the constructor does nothing now. You are opening yourself up for a whole bunch of problems if somebody else changes the structure to include a member that needs its destructore called (ie makes it non POD). The code you write now should not rely on an artifact of the current implementation that may not hold to future versions of the software (especially if the code is distributed in more than one location).

Comment: @Martin York: I'm not denying that it's generally "a bad idea", I was just prompting Noah Roberts to clarify whether or not it was strictly required or just bad practice.

Comment: @Martin: it can't be a non-POD, he's wrapping a C data structure:)

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that placement new calls are usually matched with explicit calls to the destructor.  If I have no need for a destructor (no code to put there, and no member variables that have destructors) can I safely skip the explicit destructor call?

Yes.  If I don't need to fly to New York before posting this answer, can I safely skip the trip? :)  However, if the destructor is truly unneeded because it does nothing, then what harm is there in calling it?

If the compiler can figure out a destructor should be a no-op, I'd expect it to eliminate that call.  If you don't write an explicit dtor, remember that your class still has a dtor, and the interesting case – here – is whether it is what the language calls trivial.

Solution: destroy previously constructed objects before constructing over them, even when you believe the dtor is a no-op.

> I want to write C++ bindings for a C API. In the C API many objects are accessible only by pointer. Instead of creating a wrapper object that contains a single pointer (which is wasteful and semantically confusing). I want to use placement new to construct an object at the address of the C object.

This is the purpose of layout-compatible classes and reinterpret_cast.  Include a static assert (e.g. Boost's macro, 0x static_assert, etc.) checking size and/or alignment, as you wish, for a short sanity check, but ultimately you have to know a bit of how your implementation lays out the classes.  Most provide pragmas (or other implementation-specific mechanisms) to control this, if needed.

The easiest way is to contain the C struct within the C++ type:

```
// in C header
typedef struct {
  int n;
  //...
} C_A;
C_A* C_get_a();
```

```
// your C++
struct A {
  void blah(int n) {
    _data.num += n;
  }

  // convenience functions
  static A* from(C_A *p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<A*>(p);
  }
  static A const* from(C_A const *p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<A const*>(p);
  }

private:
  C_A _data;  // the only data member
};

void example() {
  A *p = A::from(C_get_a());
  p->blah(42);
}
```

I like to keep such conversions encapsulated, rather than strewing reinterpret_casts throughout, and more uniform (i.e. compare call-site for const and non-const), hence the convenience functions.  It's also a bit harder to modify the class without noticing this type of use must still be supported.

Depending on the exact class, you might make the data member public.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: why don't you just use a cast? Then there's no issue of the placement new doing anything, and clearly no issue of failing to use a destructor. The result will work if the C and C++ types are layout compatible.

The second question is: what is the point? If you have no virtual functions, you're not using the constructor or destructor, the C++ class doesn't seem to offer any advantages over just using the C type: any methods you write should have been global functions anyhow.

The only advantage I can imagine is if you want to hide the C representation, you can overlay the C object with a class with all private members and use methods for access. Is that your purpose? [That's a reasonable thing to do I think]