# Explicitly call destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

We know that destructors are called automatically when the (**non static**) objects runs out of the declaration scope. But what if we invoke destructor explicitly?

So I have this code:

```
class A
{
public:
     A(){std::cout<<"A's ctor"<<std::endl;}
     ~A(){std::cout<<"A's dtor"<<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
      A a;
      a.~A();
}
```

And it outputs:

```
A's ctor
A's dtor
A's dtor
```

Does this mean that the object is destructed twice?

Comment: its almost never right to explicitly invoke destructors. What you have here is _undefined behavoir_ as there's no mechanism in C++ which 'remembers' you've invoked a destructor and doesn't invoke it a second time. Dont do that.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to manually call the destructor?

Comment: Not a problem but trying to understand the behavior. @MikeVine 's comment has everything sorted.

Comment: @MikeVine - Why post an answer in the comment section? I couldn't find a decent duplicate.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4580969/509868)

Comment: Be aware that the second call is undefined behaviour as you are invoking a function on an object (semantically) not existing any more at that time!

Comment: Side note: One of the very rare occasions you need to call the destructor explicitly is when you create instances via placement new...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187006/is-calling-destructor-manually-always-a-sign-of-bad-design

Comment: @StoryTeller: Answering in the comments is in vogue for some reason.  Some people even brag about it! Crazy. FWIW, answers do not go in comments, not normally and _especially_ not when there is a dupe or some other reason to close the question. Quoting SE community manager Robert Cartaino, "that is the worst of both worlds."